# Trying to get a provider from IBMQ but get 'No provider matches the criteria.'

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I have created a circuit and then run the following:
`provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')`
And this is what I get:

```
IBMQProviderError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-d651cdcd236d> in <module>
----> 1 provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\providers\ibmq\ibmqfactory.py in get_provider(self, hub, group, project)
    352 
    353         if not providers:
--> 354             raise IBMQProviderError('No provider matches the criteria.')
    355         if len(providers) > 1:
    356             raise IBMQProviderError('More than one provider matches the criteria.')

IBMQProviderError: 'No provider matches the criteria.'
```

Answer (score 2):

First try to sign-in into https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/, if not done already. There you will get to see one of IBM's free 15 qubit quantum machines named `ibmq_16_melbourne`.

If successful, try adding the following snippet:

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
job = execute(circuit, backend=qcomp)
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
from qiskit.providers.ibmq.job import job_monitor
job_monitor(job)
result = job.result()
```

If you want to come up with a histogram, try:

```
from qiskit.tools.visualization import plot_histogram
plot_histogram(result.get_counts(circuit))
```

For more info, refer to this YouTube video on [Qiskit Hello World](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RrUTwq5jKM4).

Answer (score 1):

There is no hub simply called `ibm-q`. I think what you are meaning to do is
`provider  = IBMQ.get_provider()`. What you put in the brackets is the name of the hub, for example if your school was a registered hub you might have something to write in there but most users will leave the brackets blank. After this you can do `backend = provider.get_backend(BACKEND_NAME)` to get the backend you want to use.

Comment: `ibm-q` hub is actually correct. If you go to your IBMQ dashboard, in the main page, and scroll down to the end you'll see `IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably `IBMQ.load_account()` **was missing** in your code!
*I was able to reproduce the same error message by removing `IBMQ.load_account()` from my code.*

A working example would be something like this:

```
IBMQ.load_account()

provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
qdevice = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
job = execute(qc, backend= qdevice)
result = job.result()
```