# Cannot get a provider from IBMQ

Tags: programming, qiskit, ibm-q-experience

My code is:

```
    from qiskit import IBMQ
    IBMQ.load_account()
    provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
    qcomp = provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')
```

but I run it in Jupyter I get the following message

```
    QiskitBackendNotFoundError                Traceback 
    (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-6-f874d37829a9> in <module>
      2 IBMQ.load_account()
      3 provider = IBMQ.get_provider('ibm-q')
    ----> 4 qcomp = 
    provider.get_backend('ibmq_16_melbourne')

                                                                        
 
    ~\anaconda3\lib\sitepackages\qiskit\providers
     \providers\provider.py in get_backend(self, name, 
     **kwargs)
     53             raise 
     QiskitBackendNotFoundError("More than one backend 
     matches the criteria")
     54         if not backends:
     ---> 55             raise 
     QiskitBackendNotFoundError("No backend matches the 
     criteria")
     56 
     57         return backends[0]

     QiskitBackendNotFoundError: 'No backend matches the 
     criteria'
```

I have already made an account at IBM, and have already seen the post ([Trying to get a provider from IBMQ but get 'No provider matches the criteria.'](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/11966/trying-to-get-a-provider-from-ibmq-but-get-no-provider-matches-the-criteria?newreg=2e701ee65b994f2bb3ac9924e7f2abfc)), but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backend that you choose ( 'ibmq_16_melbourne' ) was retired recently. With a different backend, it should work. You can find available IBM Quantum systems here.

https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/services?services=systems

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: Your welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer stated, this is because `ibmq_16_melbourne` is no longer in service. But in general, to know which backend is in service and available to you, you can quickly run the following script:

```
from qiskit import IBMQ, Aer
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
available_cloud_backends = provider.backends() 
print('\n Cloud backends:')
for i in available_cloud_backends: print(i)

available_local_backends = Aer.backends() 
print('\n Local backends: ')
for i in available_local_backends: print(i)
```

This will output something like:

```
 Cloud backends:
ibmq_qasm_simulator
ibmq_armonk
ibmq_santiago
ibmq_bogota
ibmq_lima
ibmq_belem
ibmq_quito
simulator_statevector
simulator_mps
simulator_extended_stabilizer
simulator_stabilizer
ibmq_manila

 Local backends: 
aer_simulator
aer_simulator_statevector
aer_simulator_density_matrix
aer_simulator_stabilizer
aer_simulator_matrix_product_state
aer_simulator_extended_stabilizer
aer_simulator_unitary
aer_simulator_superop
qasm_simulator
statevector_simulator
unitary_simulator
pulse_simulator
```

This might save you time from having to look up this info through the IBM Q webpage.

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you!